# Helpers, methods and classes organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, organization

When my project is growing up, I need to write some methods, but application_controller's private methods and helpers aren't provide enough space to store all extensions.

So I have looked at custom classes and methods, which are stored in the /lib folder.

But i still have some questions, which i can't solve:

-When should I use "class << self"? I have a class, to calculate difference between two arrays of numbers, and then return new array with a middle values of that numbers. I used to such code:

```
x = MyClass.new
x.calculate(array1, array2)
```

And then I have placed my class' methods into "class << self; end" to use class without initialization. Is it right solution?

-When should i use custom modules? Is it always need to 'include' or 'require' them? Please tell me about your modules in your projects, when do you use them?

-How can I call helper's method in the controller? I want to use in in ajax responce. For example I use helper method 'users_for_output', and if there was ajax call, my app should render only users as text, to process it with javascript after.

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't have to instantiate the class to invoke a static method, i.e.

```
MyUtil.do_something
```

Vs.

```
MyUtil.new.do_something
```

In my project I keep such methods static.

2) You can use modules when want to share a set of functionality across classes. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins) mixin vs inheritance discussion. You will get a good idea about when to use modules.

2.1) The `included` method is intended for initializing the module variables. You don't need to use it if you don't have anything initialize.

3) If you want to expose a controller method as a helper method use the `helper_method` call in your ApplicationController class.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :user_for_output
end
```