# undefined local variable or method `authenticate_admin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to view my new action in my blogs controller, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
NameError in BlogsController#new
undefined local variable or method `authenticate_admin'
```

In my blogs controller, I want to restrict the new action to admins only (admins and users are two different models). I was able to get this to work in another model. If I'm not mistaken, helpers are open to all classes. I also tried to add the code from my admins helper to the blogs helper, but that didn't work.

**Why can't my blogs controller use my authenticate_admin method?**

Thanks for lookign :)

Here are relevant files:

blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_admin, :only => [:new]

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
    @title = "New Article"
  end
end
```

admins_helper.rb

```
def authenticate_admin
  deny_admin_access unless admin_signed_in?
end 

def deny_admin_access
  redirect_to admin_login_url, :notice => "Please sign in as admin to access this page."
end

def admin_signed_in?
  !current_admin.nil?
end

def current_admin
   @current_admin ||= Admin.find(session[:admin_id]) if session[:admin_id]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `Helpers` are accessible in your `Views` not in `Controllers`.

Solution is to move your methods from **admins_helper.rb** to `ApplicationController` and set them as `helper_methods`. You will be able to access them in your `Controllers` and `Views`.

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Helpers
  helper_method :authenticate_admin

  def authenticate_admin
    deny_admin_access unless admin_signed_in?
  end 

end
```

Read documentation about `helper_method`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just had to add `include AdminsHelper` to my application_controller.rb. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is also solution - probably the simplest way. But if you will use your `authenticate_admin` everywhere, the best way is to inherit that method from `superclass` instead of including it in every class like a mixin. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins