# Rails + Devise undefined method `authenticate_admin!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two models user and admin configured with devise gem.  I get exception when apply authentication in admin controller.

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!
```

error:

```
undefined local variable or method `authenticate_admin!'
```

Admin Model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,:invitable
 end
```

Patient Model:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,:invitable
 end
```

Routes:

```
    devise_for :admins
    namespace :hospitals do
      devise_for :patients
end
```

Comment: Can you try with  the following line of code

before_filter do
    if current_admin != nil
     authenticate_admin!        
    else
     authenticate_user!
    end

Comment: Do any of the helpers work? e.g admin_signed_in?

Comment: I tried before_filder do ...end. Its not woking

Comment: helper method (admin_signed_in?) also not working.

Comment: Please post relevant model and route code.

Comment: Added routes and model

Comment: Have you added the proper initializers in config?

Comment: Yes. I added config/initializer/devise.rb. Also enabled scope_view. config.scoped_views = true

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789722/undefined-local-variable-or-method-authenticate-admin

Comment: In the application controller I include all helper methods. But I always getting session[:patient_id] as nil