# What's the point, if any, of inheritance-like composition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby inheritance vs mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins)

The following is a frequent pattern in Ruby:

```
module Persistable
  def initialize
    # Initialize a persistable document.
  end
end

class Foo
  include Persistable
end
```

What's the advantage here over simply subclassing?

```
class PersistableDocument
  def initialize
    # Initialize a persistable document.
  end
end

class Foo < PersistableDocument
end
```

In other words, why would you mix in behaviour that *defines how an object should be instantiated* if all that's accomplished is one extra line of code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code to mimick the (aging) AR vs DM debate.

Comment: @HakanEnsari "The following is a frequent pattern in Ruby:" - really? Have you come across modules that implement `initialize` in real code?

Comment: Off the top of my head, DataMapper::Resource, Mongoid::Document.

Answer (score 1):

Modules should be used when you need to share code for many classes and not only one. Think about the most common module used in Ruby, [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html). It expects to be included in an object that implements an **each** method that accepts a single argument.

Once it is included in such an object, it will provide an implementation for all its methods. So this is the case of using modules, you have a common behavior and you would like to share this behavior with many classes, then you can use a module to implement it.

Modules are not something to replace inheritance, they just allow give you another option to compose the behavior of your objects.

Comment: Enumerable is far and away the best example of the utility of modules in Ruby. I would simply add that modules are Ruby's solution to multiple inheritance, which poses problems such as: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem.

Comment: Thanks.I'm talking specifically about the use of Modules where the latter mix in #initialize.