# Rails design dilemma: same algorithm, different classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pointers, multiple-inheritance

I'm working on my first Ruby on Rails project and I am now faced with a design dilemma. I'm no professional programmer so I may be missing some pretty basic stuff. Please bear with me.

My project is a simulator of electoral systems. I have (among others) these models

```
class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :census, :name
  has_many :results
  has_many :parties, :through => :results
  belongs_to :region
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :acronym, :name
  has_many :results
  has_many :towns, :through => :results
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :party, :town, :votes, :year
  belongs_to :town
  belongs_to :party
end
```

Both classes `Town` and `Party` will have a method `seats()`, and the algorithm for computing seats (from `:census` or from `:votes`, resp.) will be essentially the same. I would like to be able to code the algorithms in a way that can be applied to either.

I have thought of various solutions:

- Code a generic function and pass it a pointer to the desired class. This has the problem that what in one case is `:census` in the other case is `:votes`, I don't know how easy it is to manage this in RoR. Can I pass a pointer to the column as well? It doesn't sound too Rubyish.
- Inherit from a common class where the algorithms are defined. Then I'd lose the ActiveRecord functionality which is actually very handy. Or would I?
- Create a generic algorithm and feed it raw arrays of data from the class-specific methods accordingly. This means that I have to code the data interface for each class separately.

I'd like the solution to be scalable, i.e., someday I'd like it to work for "regions" which will be collections of towns, and for "coalitions" which will be collections of parties...

Would you implement any of these options? What are the pros/cons of each of them? Is there a standard approach to this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins

Comment: so, there's the option of a mixin, didn't know that. Thx for the comment. Is there a way to have a module which uses :census or :votes accordingly?

Comment: Yes, move all common methods to a module, and `include` them, that's standard practice. Ideally, code in modules should be as agnostic and modular as possible, so as to create as less coupling as possible.