# Classwide method in ruby gem

Tags: ruby, class, methods, module, rubygems

How can you define c method that is accessible from class One and Two?

```
module MyGem
  class One
    def a
      c
    end
  end

  class Two
    def b
      c
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You subclass a parent class, use a mixin, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is few ways, for example [inheritance vs mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins).

Using mixins, you can define a `Module` and include in your classes.

```
module MyGem
  class One
    include Mixin

    def a
      c
    end
  end

  class Two
    include Mixin

    def b
      c
    end
  end

  module Mixin
    def c
      ...
    end
  end
end
```