# Why doesn't Ruby have the same namespace controvery as C++?

Tags: c++, ruby

One of the greatest offenses in the C++ community is [writing `using namespace xyz` instead of writing the namespace out everywhere in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Ruby has the functional equivalent of namespaces via modules. All of the proposed issues with using an entire namespace in C++ are perfectly valid for including an entire module in Ruby. But in Ruby it is not condemned to do this.

So why doesn't Ruby have the same namespace controvery as C++? What is the difference between including a module in Ruby and using a namspace in C++?

Comment: Presumably the contents of a module are well defined, whereas those of a C++ namespace aren't. But there may be a strong cultural component. Maybe in some contexts it doesn't matter as much if the code doesn't do what you think it is doing.

Comment: Why close vote? What about this question sounds like an opinion? I'm not looking for opinions. I want to know what the difference is. Why does Ruby not have the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a strong cultural component to this since it is perfectly *valid* to import an entire namespace... **BUT**

c++ has Argument Dependent Lookup (**ADL**) and ruby does not. As a program grows, it becomes more and more likely that an innocent `using namespace x` will accidentally change the meaning of the entire program, because the compiler happens to find a better match in the `x::` namespace for a function that has the same name and similar signature to one in the (for example) `y::` namespace.

This is the reason for the caution on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You generally "include" a module when you are mixing-in a functionality from one module into another. There are some parallels between mix-ins and inheritance where you are "absorbing" the functionality of one module/class into the current module/class. Here's [a comparison of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins).

However, if you aren't mixing-in functionality, then you would always use the proper namespace qualifier of the module to access its functions.

Comment: So if module A includes module B for its own purposes, and then I include module A in my program, then module B would not be included in the scope of my code? Whereas in C++ with namespaces it would be?

Comment: It would be included in the scope. You've effectively mixed B into A, so it doesn't change where you access it from. However if you want to access the functions within module A, you would still use the full namespace qualifier: `A.foo()`, `A.bar()` etc. `include` was only to merge/mix B into A.

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't pull everything via an include at top level (the equivalent of using namespace in C++). you "mix" it in where you need functionality from that specific module.